# Create a Dext for legacy codeless kext without an app?

Tags: xcode, macos, kernel-extension, driverkit, macos-system-extension

I am writing a **DriverKit** dext but I dont have any app.

My original kext requires no app.

In this case, how do I port the original codeless kext to new dext assuming I need an app to load the dext?

Answer (score 2):

You are absolutely right, you need at least a slim app to load your dext.

It is not possible to load a dext without the structure of an app bundle, MacOS prevents that and there is no way to work around it.